# Zend Cronjobs call a controller

Tags: zend-framework, controller, cron

I wanna create a cronjobs in Zend Framework. I founded some examples and now my code is like that: ( the file \public\index.php )

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH') || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));


// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library')  ,
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
    );

$application->bootstrap();

/** Cronjobs don’t need all the extra’s **/
if(!defined('_CRONJOB_') || _CRONJOB_ == false)
{
$application->bootstrap()->run();
}
?>
```

I added a new folder called cronjobs on the same level like application, and I added a new file called cronjobs.php

```
<?php
define("_CRONJOB_",true);
require('../public/index.php'); 

//HERE I NEED SOME CODE FOR CALLING EMAIL CONTROLLER

register_shutdown_function('__shutdown');

function __shutdown() {
global $time, $memory;
$endTime = microtime(true);
$endMemory = memory_get_usage();

echo '
Time [' . ($endTime - $time) . '] Memory [' . number_format(( $endMemory - $memory) / 1024) . 'Kb]';
}
?>
```

I need to **CALL** an controller in this cronjobs.php file (I have an Email Controller that I wanna call it). I need to use some actions from that controller, that will send me mail, using some views templates.
How I can do this? Can you help me?
Thanks a lot,
Bogdan.

Comment: cronjobs generally don't call the controller(not using php -f anyway). If you want to call a controller you're better off using `wget` on *nix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok .. not so easy.

First you need an dummy router, put it your application library. My namespace is "Nc" so the Class is in library/Nc/Controller/Router/Cli.php.

```
class Nc_Controller_Router_Cli extends Zend_Controller_Router_Abstract
    implements Zend_Controller_Router_Interface
{

    public function route(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $dispatcher)
    {

    }

    public function assemble($userParams, $name = null, $reset = false, $encode = true)
    {

    }

    public function getFrontController()
    {

    }

    public function setFrontController(Zend_Controller_Front $controller)
    {

    }

    public function setParam($name, $value)
    {

    }

    public function setParams(array $params)
    {

    }

    public function getParam($name)
    {

    }

    public function getParams()
    {

    }

    public function clearParams($name = null)
    {

    }

}
```

Next create an run.php script (bootstrap), maybe in your jobs folder. It can look like this:

```
<?php
$time = microtime(true);
$memory = memory_get_usage();
set_time_limit(0);

define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'cronjob');
define('CRONJOB_RUNNING', true);

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application **/
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// initialize Zend_Application
$application = new Zend_Application (
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();

$getopt = new Zend_Console_Getopt(array(
    'action|a=s' => 'action to perform in format of "module/controller/action"',
    'help|h'     => 'displays usage information',
    'list|l'     => 'List available jobs',
));

try {
    $getopt->parse();
} catch (Zend_Console_Getopt_Exception $e) {
    // Bad options passed: report usage
    echo $e->getUsageMessage();
    return false;
}

if ($getopt->getOption('l')) {
    // add help messages..
}

if ($getopt->getOption('h')) {
    echo $getopt->getUsageMessage();
    return true;
}

if ($getopt->getOption('a')) {
    $front = $application->getBootstrap()->getResource('frontcontroller');

    $params = array_reverse(explode('/', $getopt->getOption('a')));
    $module = array_pop($params);
    $controller = array_pop($params);
    $action = array_pop($params);

    if (count($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $param) {
            $splitedNameValue = explode('=', $param);
            $passParam[$splitedNameValue[0]] = $splitedNameValue[1];
        }
    } else {
        $passParam = array();
    }

    $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Simple($action, $controller, $module, $passParam);

    $front->setRequest($request)
          ->setResponse(new Zend_Controller_Response_Cli())
          ->setRouter(new Nc_Controller_Router_Cli());


    $application->run();

    $endTime = microtime(true);
    $endMemory = memory_get_usage();

    echo 'Time [' . ($endTime - $time) . '] Memory [' . number_format(( $endMemory - $memory) / 1024) . 'Kb]' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Now on your cli you can call controller action like this:

php run.php -a module/controller/action

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Now I will implement to see how it is working. I have a dummy question. You said "First you need an dummy router, put it your application library. My namespace is "Nc" so the Class is in library/Nc/Controller/Router/Cli.php." In my structure I have folders: application, application/configs, application/controller, application/layouts, application/views and public and no library (where is the application library ?). Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.... we need the code:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$loader->registerNamespace('Nc_');
```

instead of :

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
```

Thanks for help me. I found here some web page that helped me to found the bug problem:
http://webdevbyjoss.blogspot.com/2010/09/running-zend-framework-application-from.html